# How switch from GridView to ListView on click of a button in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I am building a wallpaper app and want to implement a feature of switching views, like switching from `GridView` to `ListView` on the press of an `IconButton` in FLutter

would look something like this:

The only way I could think of implementing this feature is by changing the `crossAxisCount` value in the `GridView.count()` method by hooking up a counter to the `crossAxisCount` property and controlling it through a function on click of an `IconButton`, this works but I have to Hot Reload my application every time the counter is incremented or decremented,

Any Suggestions or fix to this problem is welcomed.

Comment: My immediate guess is that you're not calling `setState` when you change you "counter".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can simply use ternary operators and `setState()` to achieve what you want.
First, declare a boolean above your `widget build`. Then you can use ternary operators to change it from gridview to listview.

```
bool isGridView=true;
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
Scaffold(
  body: isGridView ? GridView.builder():ListView.builder(),
 );
}
```

In your onPressed(), you can call `setState()`:

```
setState(() {
  isGridView=false;
});
```